undefined method `broadcast' for class ActiveSupport::Logger (NoMethodError)
i am trying to implement logger-interface
require 'rollbar/logger'

Rails.logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(Rollbar::Logger.new))

My tech stack is
ruby '3.3.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 7.1', '>= 7.1.3.2'
gem 'rollbar', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.1'

screenshot of error attached

I tried various approach
::Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::BroadcastLogger.new(Rollbar::Logger.new)
Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::BroadcastLogger.new(Rollbar::Logger.new)

and
  Rails.logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(Rollbar::Logger.new))
  rails_logger = Rollbar::Logger.new
  rails_logger.level = Logger::INFO
  rails_logger.add_logger(Rollbar::Logger.new)
  
  Rails.logger = rails_logger


broadcast was removed in favor of a new class. According to the notes broadcast was always a part of the private API, so a public interface was created in 7.1, See: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1fbd812c47f7ba840390942e56d9b2ebbc260901 and https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-1-stable/activesupport/CHANGELOG.md#rails-710rc1-september-27-2023 and https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BroadcastLogger.html
